# Illustrate content from FCE in another way

Tags: typo3

I have some FCEs which are working fine. Now I want to display the data for another render type and I have to change from div to ul. Is there a way to extract the data fields with Typoscript? Currently the FCEs are included as Page-Content Elements in another template. The data processing contains the following TS Code

```
10= RECORDS
10.source.current=1
10.tables = tt_content
10.wrap = <!--TYPO3SEARCH_begin--> | <!--TYPO3SEARCH_end-->
```

@ggzone:
I tried this:

```
10 = COA
10 {
  10 = TEXT
  10 {
    current = 1
    typolink.parameter.field = field_link_text
    required = 1
    wrap = <h3>|</h3>
  }
}
```

But I only get `<h3>39,40,57</h3>`. That are the IDs from the FCEs. How do I get the field value?

Answer (score 1):

ofcourse... this is an example how to render a FCE... u can also use a Typoscript select in there from tt_content. there are many snippets outside. for example just replace your snippet with this one just to see if it works. dont forget to edit the "field_yourfieldname" to your field_xxxx

```
10 = COA
10 {
  10 = TEXT
  10 {
    current = 1
    typolink.parameter.field = field_yourfieldname
    required = 1
    wrap = <h3>|</h3>
  }
}
```

typolink is not the only where you can use .field as typolinks uses the ID to link to a page (&id=123) you will get it. you can also use value.field or stdWrap.field.

heres another example which should work:

```
10 = HTML    
10.value.field = field_yourfieldname
```

take a look aroun in google.. its not easy to find some snippets but also not that hard. as i use this not often i also need to take a look around everytime

Comment: I think something is missing. I tried your example but I don't get an output (nothing in the HTML code). What I'm doing wrong? What do you mean with Typoscript select?

Comment: feel yourself free to use google pls... "typoscript select" ... its a way to use a SQL select from database like tt_content to get a content and rendering it.

Comment: Sorry. I tried 10.field, 10.value.field but nothing of them worked (no output). I took the field name stated in "field" when modifying DS / TO. But I got the whole thing managed through adapting the CSS ... Thanks for your help.